# Create pair values from consecutive int array elements

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to sum the first and second, then the third and fourth then the fifth and sixth elements from an array. 
For example if I get as input int[] {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, -1} I need to compute it to new int[] {3,3,3}

```
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    int[] Arr = new int[] {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, -1};
    int sum = 0;
    foreach(int index in Arr)
    {
        //sum = (Arr[index at 0 position] + Arr[item at 0 position + 1]); 
        //Then do nothing with Arr[index at 1 position]
        //Then sum Arr[index at 2 position] + Arr[item at 3 position];
        //Then do nothing with Arr[index at 4 position]

        //if I test this condition
        // if(Arr[index]%2==0) //here I want to test the actual index of the element, not the value behind the index
        //{skip the next Arr[index]}
        //else{ sum Arr[index]+Arr[index + 1] }



    }
}
```

}

Comment: In this case use a normal for loop instead of foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This Sums up each pair and leave the last as is if the length is odd:**

```
int[] Arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 0, 3, 4 };
int ExactResultLength = (int)(((double)Arr.Length / 2) + 0.5);
int[] res = new int[ExactResultLength];

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i+= 2)
{
    if(i + 1 < Arr.Length)
        res[j] = Arr[i] + Arr[i+1];
    else
        res[j] = Arr[i];

    j++;
}
```

Comment: it is like saying , if the number is odd then (number + 1 ) / 2 assuming you want to keep that last number that has no pair to add to.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't care about an element left without a pair:

```
int[] Arr = new int[] {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, -1};
int[] Arr2 = new int[Arr.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < Arr2.Length; i++)
    Arr2[i] = Arr[i * 2] + Arr[i * 2 + 1];
```

But if you do and it should come in the output array, add the following row at the end:

```
Arr2[Arr2.Length - 1] = Arr[Arr.Length - 1];
```

and also change `Arr2`'s length to `Arr.Lenght / 2 + 1`